# How do I write a Flow interface with a method that takes a class-implementing-the-interface as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, abstract-class, flowtype

I want to write an interface that defines a method which takes, as a parameter, or as a return type, something that is an instance of a class that implements this interface.

That is, I want the compiler to know that it can call the interface methods and any other methods of that class. My instinct was to try this:

```
interface Doable {
  doSomething(otherThing: Doable): Doable
  interfaceMethod(): boolean
}

class Foo implements Doable {
  doSomething(otherFoo: Foo): Foo {
    if (this.interfaceMethod() && this.nonInterfaceMethod()) {
      return otherFoo;
    } else {
      return this;
    }
  }
  interfaceMethod(): boolean {
    return true;
  }
  nonInterfaceMethod(): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}
```

However, Flow doesn't consider `Foo`'s `doSomething` method as valid, because it says `Foo` is incompatible with `Doable`.

Is it possible to use interfaces in this way? Is there some other way of doing this besides resorting to `any` on the interface method param type?

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `Doable` interface a type parameter that represents its exact subtype:

```
interface Doable<A> {
  doSomething(otherThing: A): A,
  interfaceMethod(): boolean,
}

class Foo implements Doable<Foo> {...}
```

This type parameter, and the way we implement `Doable<Foo>`, lets the typechecker track the exact implementing type in the `doSomething` method.